# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "443,80"

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-zuul, netflix-eureka, springfox, kubernetes-ingress

I am getting the following exception while hitting my backend Spring boot application which is deployed on a Kubernetes container:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "443,80"
```

All my services are registered with eureka:

```
#Eureka
spring.application.name=app-name
eureka.client.registerWithEureka=true
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=true
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://app-eureka-dev/eureka
eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true
eureka.instance.non-secure-port-enabled=true
```

And all my requests are routed through ingress/zuul services.

```
spring.application.name=app-gateway
eureka.client.registerWithEureka=false
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=true
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://app-eureka-dev/eureka
```

When we try hitting backend services from the Swagger API, I am getting below exception.

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "443,80"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at springfox.documentation.swagger2.web.HostNameProvider.componentsFrom(HostNameProvider.java:72)
    at springfox.documentation.swagger2.web.Swagger2Controller.getDocumentation(Swagger2Controller.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod
```

I am connecting to the eureka service through the container name, even though I am getting above exception. Is there any other configuration required, as we do ssl offloading in ingress, rest should be plain http or unsecure calls within the container services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should have been fixed with Springfox 2.7.0, as can be seen in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1706) and the [release notes](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1824) of this version.

Before Springfox 2.7.0, [the following code](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/blob/94f4d3f2f8f54d63d2846d8836cabd54752593da/springfox-swagger2/src/main/java/springfox/documentation/swagger2/web/HostNameProvider.java#L69-L73) was used to determine the port number in `HostNameProvider`:

```
String port = request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-Port");

if (hasText(port)) {
  builder.port(Integer.parseInt(port));
}
```

So basically it used the `X-Forwarded-Port` header to determine the port number. However, in your case it seems like it passes both the HTTP and HTTPS ports (`443,80`), which is obviously not a valid integer.

Upgrading your `springfox-swagger2` dependency to 2.7.0 (or higher) should do the trick.

Comment: how it passes 443, as i am connecting through ingress, which offloads ssl, and forward to 80 only, please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: It's because `X-Forwarded-Port` contains every port number it was ever forwarded from, so if I understand your architecture correctly, it passes Ingress on 443, which forwards it to Zuul on port 80 and adds the `X-Forwarded-Port: 443`. After that, Zuul forwards to your destination service, and adds port 80 to `X-Forwarded-Port: 443,80`.

Comment: i got it, but is it possible to restrict port to only 80 from zuul or have some configuration to change to port 80 only. so that i can avoid these kind port issues in future

Comment: @pappu_kutty You can create your own `ZuulFilter` to modify the headers. You could basically look at the code that implemented the `X-Forwarded-Port` as an example (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1807).

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem in SWAGGER when my DTO properties annotated with @APIModelProerty. Majorly, the problem occurred when Long type properties are present in the DTO object and failed to convert the empty string ("") value into 0.

So, it solved when I added example property in `@APIModelProperty(example = "1", required = "false")`.